# Replace blank date field with another date field

Tags: r

I'm trying to replace a date field that has blanks, with another date field (which may also contain blanks). I'm trying to use an ifelse function which is:

```
companies$Date.Closed <- ifelse(companies$Date.Closed== "", companies$Date.Hidden,companies$Date.Closed)
```

This isn't working. For reference of what my data looks like

```
Company    Date.Closed    Date.Hidden
CompanyA   2018-01-01     2018-01-01
CompanyB                  2018-02-01
CompanyC
CompanyD   2018-02-01
```

Note: the blanks show up as grey "NA"'s in r
Basically, if Date.Closed is blank, fill it with Date.Hidden. When I try my code above, I'm getting the

```
Error in charToDate(x):character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

But I know both my dates are in the proper format because I can use them in other lines of code, such as a subset based on date.

Thanks

dput(companies$Date.Closed) returns a bunch of NA's and a number where a date presumably existed, like: NA, NA, 17371

Comment: Your data is most likely in character format, not date format. Try `str(companies)` to see the types.

Something like 
`companies$Date.Closed <- ifelse(is.na(companies$Date.Closed), companies$Date.Hidden, companies$Date.Closed)` may work.

Comment: @AndrewLavers This worked but changed the Date.Closed value into a number rather than a "%Y-%m-%d" format

Answer (score 1):

**For future posts, it's always better to include sample data as the ouput of `dput`. That way we not only know the data but also the data types.**

---

### Solution 1: Assuming `Date.Closed` and `Date.Hidden` are `factor`s

In base R you can do

```
df$Date.Closed = ifelse(
    df$Date.Closed == "", 
    as.character(df$Date.Hidden), 
    as.character(df$Date.Closed))
df
#   Company Date.Closed Date.Hidden
#1 CompanyA  2018-01-01  2018-01-01
#2 CompanyB  2018-02-01  2018-02-01
#3 CompanyC
#4 CompanyD  2018-02-01
```

or alternatively

```
df <- transform(df, Date.Closed = ifelse(
    Date.Closed == "", 
    as.character(Date.Hidden), 
    as.character(Date.Closed)))
```

or the `tidyverse` way

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
    mutate(Date.Closed = if_else(Date.Closed == "", Date.Hidden, Date.Closed))
#   Company Date.Closed Date.Hidden
#1 CompanyA  2018-01-01  2018-01-01
#2 CompanyB  2018-02-01  2018-02-01
#3 CompanyC
#4 CompanyD  2018-02-01
```

---

### Solution 2: Assuming `Date.Closed` and `Date.Hidden` are `Date` objects

```
df %>%
    mutate(Date.Closed = if_else(is.na(Date.Closed), Date.Hidden, Date.Closed))
#   Company Date.Closed Date.Hidden
#1 CompanyA  2018-01-01  2018-01-01
#2 CompanyB  2018-02-01  2018-02-01
#3 CompanyC        <NA>        <NA>
#4 CompanyD  2018-02-01        <NA>
```

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "Company    Date.Closed    Date.Hidden
CompanyA   2018-01-01     2018-01-01
CompanyB   ''               2018-02-01
CompanyC   ''   ''
CompanyD   2018-02-01   ''", header = T)
```

Comment: First one still returned an error. Tried the tidyverse version and received this error: Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: character string is not in a standard unambiguous format.

Comment: @deslaur I cannot reproduce, because the code I give works with the sample data you give. Please edit your code to include the `dput` of your sample data.

Comment: I put a sample of dput, but the output that shows up in this console is massive, do I copy it all?

Comment: @deslaur Just choose a representative sample, perhaps `dput(companies[1:20, ])`

Comment: that resulted in a ton of data including other columns in my form. Anyway to just pull a sample of two columns? Sorry for all the questions... I really appreciate the help

Comment: make a smaller example as @deslaur suggested.
`df <- companies[1:20, c('Company', 'Date.Closed', 'Date.Hidden')]` then
`dput(df)`
twenty rows of only the specified columns

Comment: Okay, here's what we have: company = class = "factor"), Date.Closed = structure(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_), class = "Date"), Date.Hidden = structure(c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date")). It shows me that they're date objects but the mutate above is giving me an error "Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: character string is not in a standard unambiguous format."